# How 51=substring(051-3328328,1,3) in mysql

Tags: sql, mysql, join, casting, substring

[image]

This Image contains Person and Country table I want to connect based on Phone number starting three characters and country code of country table

I Wrote this query for connecting these two table

```
select *
FROM person
    left join country on country_code=substring(phone_number,1,3)
```

Doubt-----

1. How it is matching the 051 with 51 as 051 as substring is completely different from 51 as substring?

output for query by jarlh

[image]

Comment: That might work for matching `051` against `51` but will completely fail or get the wrong answer when matching `212` with `212`

Comment: Try `select phone_number, substring(phone_number,1,3) from person` and see what you get.

Comment: Oh and you are only substringing the person.phone_number and not the country.country_code

Comment: @jarlh i have tried your query and i have attached the output for that query in my question

Comment: Comparing with [lpad](https://dbfiddle.uk/Le0d74-7) doesn't work?

Comment: So is it that it is automatically doing lpad in background for comparing the country code with substring

Comment: _output for query by jarlh_ He @jarlh know what it would do, now you have to look at the results and see what the error is in your query, well one of them

Comment: Is your question whether `country_code=substring(phone_number,1,3)` will work for 051 and 51? That depends. If country_code is a string column (e.g. `VARCHAR(3)`) then '051' and '51' won't match. If country_code is a numeric column (e.g. `INT`), then the '051' will be converted internally to a number and match, because the numeric value for '051' is 51.

Comment: thanks all got the solution for this, thanks  @RiggsFolly  for the solution i tried using int data type to cast but it was throwing syntax error but unsigned worked  thanks for it  and thorsten thanks for explaination it resolved my doubt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that you are trying to equate 2 character codes like `51` with a 3 character codes like `051`

I would pick out the first 3 characters of the phone number with the substring() and convert them to an integer to do the comparison like this, then the leading zero in one side of the test will be dropped

Also as you have a column called `name` in both tables, I would
pick out the actual columns I want in the result specifically and alias them

```
select p.name as persons_name, c.name as country_name, c.country_code, p.phone_number
FROM person p
    left join country c on c.country_code = cast(substring(p.phone_number,1,3) AS UNSIGNED);
```

```
Moncef      Morocco     212 212-1234567
Maroua      Morocco     212 212-6543214
Jonathan    Peru        51  051-1234567
Meir        Israel      972 972-1234567
Rachael     Israel      972 972-0011100
```